# Seperate all words in a text file

Tags: java, io

I want to seperate all words in a text file. There can be lots of words in one line. I tried that code but didnt work.What can i do?

this is text file:

```
desem ki vakitlerden
bir nisan akşamıdır
rüzgarların en ferahlatıcısı senden esiyor
sen de açıyor çiçeklerin en solmazı
ormanların en kuytusunu sen de gezmekteyim
demişken sana ormanların
senden güzeli yok
vakitlerden geçmekteyim
çiçeklerin tadı yok çiçeklerin
neyi var çiçeklerin
```

and i want to write all the words one bye one.

```
String[] words = null;
String line = inputStream.nextLine();


        while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            line = inputStream.nextLine();
            words = line.split(" ");
        }


            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(words[i]);
            }
        }
        inputStream.close();
```

Comment: "I tried that code but didn't work" doesn't tell us anything about what you expected to happen vs what actually happened.

Comment: Use [edit] options to add more informations (for instance: input and code examples) to your question.

Comment: i want to seperate all the words one bye one in  a paragraph and write them.

Comment: i added more info thanks Pshemo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already seem to be using `Scanner`

instead of

```
while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
    line = inputStream.nextLine();
    words = line.split(" ");
}


    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(words[i]);
    }
}
```

you can use its `next()` which will read words instead of lines. This way you will be able to print all words without having to

1. read entire line,
2. parse this line to `split` it into words
3. store all words

Your code can look like:

```
Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new File("location/of/your/file.txt"));
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
while (inputStream.hasNext()){
    words.add(inputStream.next());
}
inputStream.close();

for (String word : words){
     //here you can do whatever you want with each word from list
     System.out.println(word);
}
```

Comment: I tried but it didnt worked. it returns only last word.

Comment: my output just this:
çiçeklerin

Comment: my codeis that:        String[] words = null;*********
  ************while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
   ********line = inputStream.next();
   **********words = line.split(" ");
  }
  ***********for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
   ***********System.out.println(words[i]);
  }
  ************inputStream.close();
 }

Comment: @OzanSelcukGumus `next()` doesn't read lines, but words. That is why when you do `words = line.split(" ");` you are actually creating array with one word, and storing it under `words` reference. That is why your other loop only prints one word. I updated my answer with more code. Hope it is clearer how you should use this approach.

Comment: It worked but didn't write first three words. I didn't get. Why it worked like that?Also i forgot to say that i have to assign all the words to an array.I'm sorry about that . I couldnt do assign the array also. @Pshemo

Comment: To assign words to array you would need to know number of words first, so you could create array with correct size. So instead consider using `List` like `ArrayList` which can handle resizing (copy small array to bigger one if needed) for you. I will update my answer with example.

Comment: About "but didn't write first three words" I would need to see your code. It looks like you are reading them somewhere else without using them (probably by invoking `nextLine()`), but I can't say where without seeing actual code.

Comment: i'm sorry. I forgot the delete the line when i assign the line out of loop. Thank you so much. I'll update my code about array.@Pshemo

Comment: it is working like that.Thank you so much for all your answers. It worked a lot and i learned a lot.Thanks again. @Pshemo

Comment: can i ask one more question:) if i searched one of the word which is in the text how can i get and write his column and line?can you give an idea?@Pshemo

Comment: @OzanSelcukGumus For this task it is better to read text line-by-line using `nextLine()` and test if current line contains your word. You can use something like `int position = line.indexOf(searchedWord);`. If value of position will be `-1` then line doesn't contain such string, if it will be more than `-1` like `42` then it means that word exist inside this line and it is in column `42`,

Comment: Thanks a lot again.it was really my last question.@Pshemo

Answer (score 2):

Use ArrayList:

```
 ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
 String line = inputStream.nextLine();


    while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
        line = inputStream.nextLine();
        words.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")));
    }


        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(words.get(i´));
        }
    }
    inputStream.close();
```